# how to loop through nested array

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a nested array which looks like this:

```
"meetingTime":[
         [
            {
               "date":"2021-05-30",
               "startTime":"15:30",
               "endTime":"11:11"
            }
         ],
         [
            {
               "date":"2021-06-29",
               "startTime":"17:00",
               "endTime":"19:00"
            }
         ],
         [
            {
               "date":"2021-06-29",
               "startTime":"14:00",
               "endTime":"15:06"
            },
            {
               "date":"2021-06-29",
               "startTime":"14:00",
               "endTime":"12:00"
            }
         ]
      ]
   }
]
```

What I want to do now is looping through this array and outputting for each date the available times. For example in this example it would be startTime 14:00 - 12:00 and startTime 14:00 - 15:06 for the 2021-06-29 date. this is how I construct my array:

```
<script>
import DatePickerComponent from "@/components/DatePickerComponent";

export default {
  name: "GenerateMeetingSettings",

  data: () => ({
    selectedTime: [],
    finalMeeting: [],
    datesFinal: [{meetingName: "",
      meetingTime: []}] ,
    dates: new Date().toISOString().substr(0,10),
    meetingSettingUrl: "",
    meetingPW: "",
    generatedLink: false,
    meetingName: "",
    dialog: false,
    menu: false,
    modal: false,
    menu2: false,
    menu3: false
  })
,

  methods:{

    addTimeFields(){
      this.selectedTime.push({
        date: this.dates,
        startTime:"",
        endTime: "",
      })
    },
    saveDateAndTIme(e) {
        this.datesFinal[0].meetingTime.push(this.selectedTime),

          this.selectedTime = []


    },
```

and this is what I tried to display the values but had no luck with this try, maybe someone can help me here:

edit

```
<v-col cols="12" v-for="(time, timeIndex) of time.meetingTime" key="index2">
    <h4>{{i.meetingTime.date}}</h4>
    <v-chip-group v-if="i.times.length !== 0">
      <v-chip v-for="(time, timeIndex) in time.meetingTime" :key="timeIndex">{{
          time.startTime + ":" + time.endTime
        }}</v-chip>
    </v-chip-group>
  </v-col>
```

edit error:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "time" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

found in

---> <GenerateMeetingSettings> at src/components/GenerateMeetingSettings.vue
       <Home> at src/views/Home.vue
         <VMain>
           <VApp>
             <App> at src/App.vue
               <Root>

eval @ main.js?56d7:21
./src/main.js @ app.js:1273
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:849
fn @ app.js:151
1 @ app.js:1358
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:849
checkDeferredModules @ app.js:46
(anonymous) @ app.js:925
(anonymous) @ app.js:928
Show 48 more frames
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'meetingTime' of undefined"

found in

---> <GenerateMeetingSettings> at src/components/GenerateMeetingSettings.vue
       <Home> at src/views/Home.vue
         <VMain>
           <VApp>
             <App> at src/App.vue
               <Root>

vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: Cannot read property 'meetingTime' of undefined
    at Proxy.render (GenerateMeetingSettings.vue?90fe:384)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3548)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4066)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4479)
    at new Watcher (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4468)
    at mountComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4073)
    at VueComponent.Vue.$mount (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8415)
    at init (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118)
    at createComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5978)
    at createElm
```

Comment: What was the error? If you had syntax error, can you check this? `v-for="(time, timeIndex) of time.meetingTime"` => `v-for="(time, timeIndex) in time.meetingTime"`

Comment: I edited the last part with how you did it. but I am getting the following error which is under the edited part

Comment: your code has no object called `time` which you are trying to access in the loop (by accessing `time.meetingTime`)

Answer (score 0):

There are several parts that don't make sense in the code.

1. `<h4>{{i.meetingTime.date}}</h4>` Where `i` is decleared?
2. `<v-chip-group v-if="i.times.length !== 0">` Does `i` have `times` property?

Here is my code which is not tested.

```html
<v-col cols="12" v-for="(timesForDate, i) in meetingTime" key="i">
  <h4>{{ timesForDate[0].date }}</h4>
  <v-chip-group v-if="time.length">
    <v-chip v-for="(time, j) in timesForDate" :key="j">
      {{ time.startTime + ":" + time.endTime }}
    </v-chip>
  </v-chip-group>
</v-col>
```

Here `meetingTime` in the first loop is `meetingTime` array that was given in the post. As it is object value, this can surely be replaced with object.key type, i.e `datesFinal.meetingTime`

Comment: I just tested it but still the same error where times can not be found

Answer (score 0):

`<v-col cols="12" v-for="(time, timeIndex) of time.meetingTime" key="index2">` is looking for a variable called time, because you wanted it to loop through `time.meetingTime`.

Your `data` doesn't contain a field called `time` so that is why you're getting the error. You might have meant to use `selectedTime` ?

Comment: the problem is selected time is getting pushed into datesFInal and I am trying to get the information after they are pushed into datesFinal. Because through selectedTime datesFinal gets user inputted date and time values which I want to show,